# Prove a geometry related equation.

Tags: geometry

$\Delta ABC$ is an isosceles triangle. $\angle BAC$ is an right angle. $BC$ is its hypotenuse and $P$ is any point on $BC$. Prove that, $PB^2+PC^2=2\times PA^2$.

I have tried it in many ways and searched on the internet too but failed. Please someone help me.

Comment: Have you considered using coordinates? You could take $A$ to be the origin and $AB$ and $AC$ to be the axes. Then if you let $P=(x,y)$, you can find $y$ in terms of $x$ by finding the equation of the line $BC$. Then you can use the distance formula to prove what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let M be the midpoint of BC.  Then AP = $\sqrt{AM^2 + MP^2}$.  As the triangle is isoceles right, AM = BM = CM = 1/2BC.

Wolog lets assume P (which could be the same as M) is equal to or to the "left" of M.  (So BP + MP = BM and CM + MP = CP).  I.E  [B...P..M......C].

$PC^2 = (CM + MP)^2 = CM^2 + MP^2 + 2(CM*MP) = (AM^2 + MP^2) + 2(CM*MP) = AP^2 + 2(CM*MP)=AP^2 + 2(AM*MP)$

$BP^2 = (BM - MP) = (BM^2 + MP^2) - 2(BM*MP) = (AM^2 + MP^2) - 2(AM*MP)=AP^2 - 2(AM*MP)$

$PC^2 + BP^2 = 2AP^2 +  2(AM*MP) - 2(AM*MP) = 2AP^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It often helps to draw a picture:

[image]

The red lines are parallel to the legs of the triangle, therefore they
they "cut off" two smaller isosceles right triangles from $\triangle ABC$
(why?) and therefore the two segments marked $x$ are equal and the
two segments marked $y$ are equal (why?).

Now for each of the expressions
$(PA)^2$, $(PB)^2$, and $(PC)^2$,
can you see any other expressions you can substitute for them
(hint: consider $x$ and $y$ as the legs of right triangles)
in order to show that $(PB)^2+(PC)^2=2 (PA)^2$?

Answer (score -1):

First, we can express $BP$ and $PC$ via $AP$ and $\alpha = \angle PAB$ as

$BP^2 = a^2 + AP^2 - 2a AP\cos\alpha$ and $PC^2 = a^2 + AP^2 - 2a AP\sin\alpha$.

Then, 
\begin{equation}
BP^2 + PC^2 = 2a^2 + 2AP^2 - 2a AP(\cos\alpha + \sin\alpha).~~~(1)
\end{equation}

Now, we find the area of the main triangle in two ways

$Area = \frac{1}{2}a^2 = \frac{1}{2}a AP\cos\alpha + \frac{1}{2}a AP\sin\alpha = \frac{1}{2}a AP(\cos\alpha + \sin\alpha)$,

from where it follows that $a = AP((\cos\alpha + \sin\alpha))$. This can be inserted in Eq. $(1)$, and the result is what we wanted.

Hope this helps.